# Is there an antonym of "ruthless"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Is there a word that means the opposite of *ruthless*? I don’t think *ruthful* is a real word.

Comment: Ruthless: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/ruthless

Comment: Depending on the particular kind of ruthlessness you are seeking the reverse of, you might wind up with anything from _fair-minded_ to _considerate_ to _scrupulous_ to _sporting_ as an antonym of _ruthless_.

Comment: @Josh61 Those aren't actual antonyms though - they are just dissimilar words, none of which really mean the opposite. e.g. someone can be calm and civilized, but still be ruthless.

Comment: If none of those terms fits your needs, I suggest you give a full and precise definition of the connotation of ruthless you have in mind.

Comment: I would say "clement" or "lenient" could serve as  opposite of ruthless.

Comment: when in doubt, just google it. ruthful+google=results.

Comment: You need to explain what kind of antonym you mean. Do you mean someone who is unrelentingly good? Do you mean someone who is weakly bad?

Comment: So if someone is being faux-nice... are they being "ruthy"?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

While you can easily choose an antonym of ruthless  [here](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/ruthless), it is worth noting that *[ruthful](http://www.word-detective.com/2010/12/ruthless/)*  was actully a term used in the past:

> - “Ruth” was a common word in Middle English, first appearing (as “reuthe”) around the 12th century, meaning “pity or compassion,” and in the 13th century we spoke of a person who was kind, charitable, and just generally felt your pain as being “ruthful.” ***(“Ruthful” has also been used at times to mean “inspiring compassion or pity,” i.e., pathetic, as well as “expressing grief” as in “ruthful weeping,” but these are secondary senses.)***
> - A person who lacked those qualities of kindness and charity, whose only concern was for personal gain and never shed a tear for the victims of his greed, has been, since the early 14th century, known as “ruthless,” literally lacking the quality of “ruth.”
> - ***The “ruth” in “ruthful” and “ruthless” is a noun formed on the verb “to rue,” meaning “to feel sorrow or regret”*** (“And yet … no sooner was alone, Than she for loneliness her promise rued,” 1885), and which is still in wide use today (although perhaps not as much as it should be). Rue,” in turn, came from the Old English “hreowan,” which meant “to afflict with sorrow, pity or regret,” and which was rooted in old Germanic and possibly Norse words. “Rue” is perhaps most often found today in phrases such as “rue the day” (or hour, etc.), meaning, of course, to regret a decisive event which took place at that time (“France, thou shalt rue this houre within this houre,” Shakespeare, The Life and Death of King John, 1595).
> - ***While “ruthless” is alive and well in popular usage today (and “ruthlessness” is even celebrated as a virtue on Wall Street), the sweet and gentle “ruthful” has almost entirely faded from our collective memory***. The Oxford English Dictionary labels the word “archaic,” and its most recent citation for its use in print dates from the early 19th century. A search of Google News today for “ruthful” produces the epitaph “Your search – ruthful – did not match any documents,” which a quick perusal of the grim headlines confirms. It seems that this world could do with a “ruth transfusion” as soon as possible.

(www.word-detective.com)

Comment: Can't upvote twice.

Comment: Just want to mention that if a direct antonym is needed, [you want to use rueful, not ruthful](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rueful%2Cruthful&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Crueful%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brueful%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRueful%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cruthful%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bruthful%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRuthful%3B%2Cc0) going off this ngram. Ruthful is very uncommon.

Comment: That would also explain the girls name "Ruth"

Comment: @ArtB No. That one has a Biblical source.

Comment: @Dispenser: I might be missing something, but how is rueful an antonym of ruthless?

Comment: The modern dutch verb 'rouwen' (to mourn) shares the etmological root hreowan (saying that out loud for me actually brings out the same sounds), I never knew the connection between ruthless and 'rouwen' +1

Comment: @sumelic, rueful, as defined by most dictionaries, is about "expressing or inspiring sorrow or regret" [Collins as an example](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rueful). Ruthless is similarily about "displaying a lack of mercy" [also Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ruthless). Rue-ful(l), ruth-less. If you look at the etymology for [ruth](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ruth&allowed_in_frame=0) you see that it's a proto-germanic change of "rue". Same root, opposite suffix.

Comment: funny, I have heard people say "with ruth" before, to indicate the opposite of ruthless.

Comment: My daughter's middle name is Rewthe; we gave it to her after one of Chaucer's spellings (slightly different from the one you mention, which is also in Chaucer). I think we were thinking something like you last sentence when we did this.

Answer (score 20):

To lift an answer from Josh61's clear and *ruthful* reply, you could well use **compassionate**

> **compassion:** a strong feeling of sympathy and sadness for the suffering or bad luck of others and a wish to help them:
>
> *I was hoping she might show a little compassion.*
>
> *[Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/compassion)*

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ruthless) uses "compassion" in its definition of "ruthless":

> ruth·less  (ro͞oth′lĭs) adj. Having no compassion or pity; merciless:
>   ruthless cruelty; ruthless opportunism.

What I feel is missing from most of the definitions I've read is the sense that to be *ruthless*, you have to commit the acts which cause suffering (although this is often implied). Here it is, though, in the [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/ruthless) Dictionary

> [**ruthless:**] willing to make other people suffer so that you can achieve your aims.

So *ruthless* is to be willing to cause suffering and *compassionate* is to want to relieve suffering.

Answer (score 7):

*Ruthlessness* is [a lack of compassion or pity for others](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ruthless) (OED). It's a common symptom of psychopathy (i.e. psychopaths, who have difficulty empathizing with other people, tend to be *ruthless*). A *ruthless* person doesn't slow down for anyone. Such a person might also be called *aggressive* and *cutthroat* if their ruthlessness applies to advancement in competition, or policy in business or government. On the other hand, if a person is ruthless in the endeavors of their personal lives, they might be called *selfish* and *callous*.

Your search for an antonym can start with the core definition: *compassion*, *pity*, and *empathy* are all opposite of *ruthlessness*. Therefore *compassionate*, *sorry*, and *empathetic* are opposites of *ruthless*.

If you prefer, consider a more context-specific term:

A person with power over the lives of others would be called *merciful*, *gracious*, or *benevolent* if they didn't use their power ruthlessly.

In competition, if one competitor gains the upper hand over another, they would be called *sporting* and *fair* if they refrained from using their advantage to dominate their opponent more than is necessary to win, or especially if they willingly level the playing field instead to give their opponent a chance to catch up.

If you're not being ruthless in personal matters, then you're being *considerate* of the feelings of the people in your life, *sensitive* to their needs, and *caring*.

Comment: +1 for "merciful" - this is the word which instantly sprang into my mind when I read the question title.

Answer (score 2):

While most of the dictionary definitions define "ruthless" as "having no pity or compassion", I feel that it bears a connotation of "*acting* without pity or compassion".  That is, the emphasis is on *doing* rather than on simply *being*.

With that in mind, I'd suggest as an antonym "**conscientious**", which is defined by Merriam-Webster as "very careful about doing what you are supposed to do : concerned with doing something correctly", and "governed by or conforming to the dictates of conscience".

Comment: *Conscientious* requires clarification if you want it to relate to *ruthless* (e.g. "conscientous of others' feelings"). Otherwise you're assuming "right" and "wrong" directly correlate to "considering how other people feel" and "ignoring how other people feel", which may or may not be true.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree.  I think it's a given that a conscience is concerned with other people's feelings.  My conscience bothers me when I act in a way that hurts other people, and only when they're hurt.  What is "hurt" but a feeling?

Comment: When other peoples' feelings conflict, you can't please everyone. Or when accommodating other peoples' feelings affects the wellbeing of the group as a whole, it may be better to focus on the goal than on keeping people happy. Deciding to ignore peoples' feelings in these scenarios is certainly ruthless, and probably not unconscionable.

Comment: Is it not possible to be conscientiously ruthless?

Answer (score 1):

[Compassionate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/compassionate):

> - Feeling or showing compassion; sympathetic.(AHD)

also:

- kind or gentle.

Comment: Hi whiteboyyyy jym and welcome to ELU! This is a great answer, but you should consider adding definitions for each of the words you suggested.

Comment: This answer has already been suggested by @Margana http://english.stackexchange.com/a/263451/44619

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I'm afraid duplicate answers are actively discouraged and may be deleted. I'm not doing that unilaterally because you have provided synonyms for *compassionate* which haven't been given already.

Answer (score 1):

As a central connotation of ruthlessness is lack of *mercy* or *forgiveness*, I think *magnanimous* is appropriate:

> mag·nan·i·mous  (măg-năn′ə-məs)
>
> adj. Highly moral, especially in showing kindness or forgiveness, as in overlooking insults or not seeking revenge.
>
> [*The Free Dictionary*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/magnanimous)

Moreover, I feel these words naturally complement each other, since both are often used to describe powerful or political figures. One might speak of a [*ruthless dictator*](http://elitedaily.com/news/politics/7-worst-dictators-world/) or a [*ruthless despot*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/despot), and one might speak of a [*magnanimous ruler*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/magnanimous) or a [*magnanimous statesman*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ihD_7R7IzXEC&pg=PA56&dq=magnanimous+statesman&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMImcGh74CHxwIVzxGSCh3qVgFA#v=onepage&q=magnanimous%20statesman&f=false), for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Ruthless has many shades of meaning. A good all-purpose word that serves as an antonym for most (maybe all) of them might be **soft**.

They are sometimes used in contradistinction to each other, for instance in this newspaper headline:

> "Our 1984 culture of spying? Blame New Labour who were soft on criminals yet ruthless on the innocent" — *[Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/debate/article-2057582/New-Labour-soft-criminals-ruthless-innocent.html)* (4 November 2011)

Or this quote from artist Jenny Holzer:

> "I wanted to be soft like Rothko and ruthless like Ad Reinhardt." — ["Celebrate With Us As Jenny Holzer Turns 65 Years Old Today"](https://news.artnet.com/people/jenny-holzer-birthday-artist-turns-65-320476), *artnet* (29 July 2015)

Answer (score 0):

**Forgiving**

It doesn't necessarily mean the forgiving of a sin or a crime. It can mean someone who is more tolerant towards you, or even a user interface can be forgiving if it doesn't mess up the system upon minor user errors.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Benubird et al.,

When I was a kid, my father used to love showing me his collection of black-and-white "Flash Gordon" movie serials, from the 1940s.  The central antagonist, whose main purpose in life was to subjugate the entire universe, was the fiendish "Emperor Ming," a.k.a."Ming the Merciless," the ultra-tyrannical dictator of the planet Mongo. There was nothing that this character would not do, nor individual he would not betray and torture, nor lies he would not fabricate, and people he would not enslave, in order to carry out his ruthless conquests.
   I came across Stack Exchange purely by accident, and after reading a few of the questions and answers, I immediately joined.  I like words, and I like being easily understood, because I can usually utilize just one or two, that accurately convey my message. 
   Because Emperor Ming was so ruthless that he was billed as "Merciless," I submit the word "Merciful," as my response to your request for assistance in determining the most precise antonym for "Ruthless."